# Вытащить title YouTube видео

Tags: java, android, youtube-android-api

Как вытащить `title` у YouTube видео?

Имеется адаптер, который показывает картинки самих видео из YouTube, хотел бы настроить показ названия видео, но как?

Сам адаптер:

```
public class videoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<videoAdapter.VideoInfoHolder> {

    List<String> videos = new ArrayList<>();
    Context ctx;

    public videoAdapter(Context context, List<String> urls) {
        videos = urls;
        this.ctx = context;
    }

    @Override
    public VideoInfoHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.video_item, parent, false);
        int height = parent.getHeight() / 4;
        itemView.setMinimumHeight(height);
        return new VideoInfoHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final VideoInfoHolder holder, final int position) {


        final YouTubeThumbnailLoader.OnThumbnailLoadedListener  onThumbnailLoadedListener = new YouTubeThumbnailLoader.OnThumbnailLoadedListener(){
            @Override
            public void onThumbnailError(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeThumbnailLoader.ErrorReason errorReason) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onThumbnailLoaded(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, String s) {
                youTubeThumbnailView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.tvTitle.setText("Название видео");
                holder.relativeLayoutOverYouTubeThumbnailView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        };
        holder.youTubeThumbnailView.initialize(Config.YOUTUBE_API_KEY, new YouTubeThumbnailView.OnInitializedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeThumbnailLoader youTubeThumbnailLoader) {

                youTubeThumbnailLoader.setVideo(videos.get(position));
                youTubeThumbnailLoader.setOnThumbnailLoadedListener(onThumbnailLoadedListener);
            }

            @Override
            public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {}
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return videos.size();
    }

    public class VideoInfoHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        protected RelativeLayout relativeLayoutOverYouTubeThumbnailView;
        YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView;
        TextView tvTitle;
        protected ImageView playButton;

        public VideoInfoHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            playButton= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnYoutube_player);
            playButton.setOnClickListener(this);
            tvTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title_youtube_video);
            relativeLayoutOverYouTubeThumbnailView = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout_over_youtube_thumbnail);
            youTubeThumbnailView = (YouTubeThumbnailView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.youtube_thumbnail);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent(
                    (Activity) ctx,
                    Config.YOUTUBE_API_KEY,
                    videos.get(getLayoutPosition())
            );
            ctx.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Android Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/) предназначен только для проигрывания видео (ну и thumbnail'ов), чтоб инфо о видео получить надо пользовать [Youtube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list), отдельным запросом:

> `GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id={VIDEO_ID}&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`

вернется вся необходимая вам (и даже сверх того) информация.